# Controlling glyphicon spacing and text link within a unordered list for a horizonatial nav menu

Tags: html, css

How do I control vertical spacing between 2 items stacked, centered and vertically within an unordered list item? This is a glyphicon on top of the text link within an unordered list item in my navigation menu.

What would be the CSS rules for such a thing to happen.

```
<!Doctype html>
 <html lang="en-us">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" title="style">

 <head>
 <style type="text/css">

/*

Adding display: inline-block; as a style attribute will display the content horizontally. Add that to the Nav's 

<li> elements in css. I'm guessing every <li> may have a glyph. Add text-align:center on the <li>'s within the 

nav in css to align the <li>'s content in the middle.  

*/


*{
margin:0; 
padding:0;
}

/* To target only one icon, */

.glyphicon.glyphicon-globe {
    padding:3px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 -15px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}


nav {
width: 100%; 
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
background:#87e0fd;
color:#f00;

}


nav ul {
margin:0; 
padding:0;
width:100%;
line-height:50px;
height:auto;
list-style:none;
}


nav li {
display: inline-block;
width:110px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
padding:auto;
margin:0; 
border-left: solid 1px #999;
}

/* Puts border on right side of menu */

nav li:last-child {
border-right: solid 1px #999;
}



/* To target the Hover Action or Active you could write the css like below. */

nav li:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background:#3f4c6b;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
}

nav li:active {
text-decoration: none;
margin: -15px 0 0 0;

} 


 </style>

  <title>My Glyphicon Navigation Menu </title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <nav>
    <ul>

      <li>
        <link href="#" title="HOME">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span><br>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">Home</span>
       </link>
      </li>


      <li>
        <link href="#" title="ABOUT">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span><br>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">about</span>
       </link>
      </li>


      <li>
        <link href="#" title="CONTACT">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span><br>
        <span class="glyphicon-class">Contact</span>
       </link>
      </li>


    </ul>
    </nav>


  <p>Hello World</p>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle and describe more specific what you want to do? do you want more space between the glyphicon and text or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how you can do it, by adding this to your css :

```
/* Adding margin between glyphicon and text */
.glyphicon-class {
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;    
}
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b6tabykq/1/

If you wanted to remove the spaces, I don`t know what you wanted to, you should remove your < br > tag in html..

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b6tabykq/2/

Comment: Hi Patricmj, I actually wanted to have the globe on top of the text within the list item both centered vertically and horizontally with a small amount of space in between the text and glyphicon.... not next to the text.  Thx mrjap1

Comment: You can do that with margin, can't you? I don`t understand what you wanna do, but you can just change the values of the margins to do what you wanna do.

e.g : http://jsfiddle.net/b6tabykq/3/